# How to pass a method as a Binding variable to Groovy's ConfigSlurper?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I was able to bind an object on Groovy's ConfigSlurper but not a method. Is that not possible?

Here's an example

```
String conf = """

k1 = "v1"

environments{

    prod{
         person.create("prod.id1"){
            name = "prod.name1"
        }
    }

    dev {
        person.create("dev.id1"){
            name = "dev.name1"
        }

    }
}

environments{

    prod{
         create("prod.id2"){
            name = "prod.name2"
         }

    }

    dev {
        create("dev.id2"){
            name = "dev.name2"
        }


    }
}


"""

def parser = new ConfigSlurper("prod")
Person person1 = new Person()
Person person2 = new Person()
parser.setBinding([person: person1, // <-- SUCCESS
                   create: person2.&create]) // <-- NOT SUCCESS?

println parser.parse(conf)
println "person1=${person1.dump()}"
println "person2=${person2.dump()}"


class Person{

    String id
    String name

    public void create(String id, Closure c){
       this.id = id
       this.with(c)
    }


}
```

Output is

```
[k1:v1, create:prod.id2, create.name:prod.name2]
person1=<Person@409b0772 id=prod.id1 name=prod.name1>
person2=<Person@205ee81 id=null name=null>
```

Please ignore any design flaws in the example.

Comment: Try using `create.call() {}`

Comment: Could you please share what you want to achieve? Probably the `ConfigSlurper` is not right way to do it in the first place

Comment: @Dany Thanks, `.call()` works.  I'm planning to design a DSL and one of the requirements is to support environment specificity. While `create.call(..)` works, is there a way to eliminate the need to use `call`?

Comment: this is probably a bug in Groovy itself, I'll check when I get back to my computer

Comment: Thanks very much. However, could you also confirm that `person.create(..)` working fine under an `environments.xyz` block is NOT a bug; it's an intended feature, right?

Comment: `environments` case is unrelated here. This works the same way both inside and outside `environments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`person.create(...)` is translated by Groovy to `getProperty('person').invokeMethod('create', ...)`, it works since `person` is defined in the binding and `create` is defined on object returned by `getProperty('person')`.

`create.call(...)` works because it's translated to `getProperty('create').invokeMethod('call', ...)`. `create` property is defined via binding and it is of `MethodClosure` type which has `call` method defined.

However `create(...)` is translated to `invokeMethod('create', ...)`. It fails because there is no method `create` and you cannot define methods via binding.

Comment: Thanks. It's somewhat orthogonal but could you also let me know how to find out about `translated` code or share some references?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no references, still you may debug and what happens inside